# Convert dict to specific byte format

Tags: python, django, encoding, utf-8, hmac

I am trying to create a Python client for making a HMAC authenticated request to a Django application. I am having trouble recreating the payload byte format that the Django app is using to generate the signature, and therefore I cannot recreate the signature value.

the Django app is passing in the request body (before decoding) into the signature function in the format:

`b'key=value'`

where the payload is:

`{ "key":"value"}`

I have tried both:

`str({ "key": "value" }).encode("UTF-8")`

and

`json.dumps({ "key": "value" }).encode("UTF-8")`

but both of them return:

`b"{'key': 'value'}"`

What is the this format (`b'key=value'`) and how can I recreate it from a dict?

Comment: You mean a querystring?

Comment: this is a POST request with a body and no string params. Is Django converting the body to a querystring?

Comment: Do you want `request.body`?

Comment: no I'm saying request.body is in this format. This is before the request is decoded etc. How can I recreate this on the client?